# Jquery $.ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and trying to get a result using an Ajax call with jQuery. I have a Select Box where the options are being populated from the database like this:

```
echo "<select id=\"agent_select\" name =\"agent_select\" >";
echo "<option id=\"0\" value=\"0\" selected=\"selected\">Select Agent Name</option>";
$rs=$this->Model_ocperformance->get_all_activeusers_except($this->session->userdata('id'));
foreach($rs->result() as $row){
    echo "<option id=\"".$row->id."\" value=\"".$row->id."\" >".$row->name."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<div id=\"results\">
</div>";
```

My JQuery Script is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#agent_select").change(function(){
            $.ajax({    
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"<?=base_url()?>index.php/ajax/find_status",
                    data:{agent_id:$(this).val()},
                    success:function(response){
                        alert("Response: "+ response);},
                    error:function(){
                        alert("Failed to retrieve information");
                        }
                });

        });
    });
```

When I change the select box it should call the ajax function and retrieve the data from ajax/find_status function. But unfortunately nothing happens. Did I miss something or made a mistake?

Comment: Do you have an error in the console?

Comment: First, show us the **generated** HTML and JavaScript, not the PHP code. Second, are there any errors in the browser's JS console? "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: are u including jquery.js

Comment: ALso, `baseurl` followed by `index.php` seems wrong. If you need the index.php (i.e. you are not using htaccess url rewrites), then `base_url` should contain `index.php`. Confirm that the url is correct

Comment: url: <?=base_url()?> + "index.php/ajax/find_status",

Comment: URL is correct. And no errors where found. I used Google Chrome's Development Tools

Comment: can you post your server side code or make a jsfiddle so we can test this?

Comment: `<?=base_url()?>` What is the output?

Answer (score 0):

I guess error is here:

```
 url:"<?=base_url()?>index.php/ajax/find_status"
```

try with this one:

```
url:"<?php base_url(); ?>/index.php/ajax/find_status"
```

try adding `php` instead of short one `=` and try with adding `/` before index.php

Comment: Why does EVERYONE use `base_url()` when generating application URLs? `site_url()` is what you should be using. If you ever change your URLs to add/remove index.php or similar, using `base_url()` will instantly break your app.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I had problems with other scripts in the page which is why this didn't work. @Jai if I add the `php` instead of `=` then I would also have to use the `echo`. But the one I used worked after I fixed other scripts of the page.